# How should I use the nullable type if it has a value

Tags: c#, nullable

I have my Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? Date1 { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? Date2 { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? Date3 { get; set; }
```

It's important for Data1 to Data3 to be `DateTime?`

My problem:

```
//Return right value
(model.Date1.ToString().AsDateTime().ToShortDateString() != "01.01.0001" ? model.Date1.ToString().AsDateTime().ToShortDateString() : "Is not known")
//Return bad value
(model.Date2.ToString().AsDateTime().ToShortDateString() != "01.01.0001" ? model.Date1.ToString().AsDateTime().ToShortDateString() : "Není známo")
//Return bad value
(model.Date3.ToString().AsDateTime().ToShortDateString() != "01.01.0001" ? model.Date3.ToString().AsDateTime().ToShortDateString() : "Is not known")
```

I dont know how or why but input is same but `Date2` and `Date3` returns bad value...

Thanks for any help

Comment: The one thing we can be sure of: it isn't a "random" decision. What does a "bad value" mean here? what inputs did you have, and what values did you see that were unexpected? and - genuine question: why are you doing a `ToString().AsDateTime().ToShortDateString()`? what are you trying to *do* here? Also, note that locale means this is a very dangerous way of doing things (as well as being inefficient); are you sure you shouldn't be checking for `DateTime.MinValue` or similar? Note: since we don't have your `AsDateTime()` method, we can't test anything here

Comment: Second line has Date1.ToString instead of Date2? Also with a Nullable value you can use `.HasValue`  or `model.Date3?.ToString()` to check if it is not null.

Comment: better you should write this code in the `set` and throw the exception if it is not according to the requirement

Comment: @DTul good eyes, there! unfortunately, OP reports that `Date3` also gives "bad value", and `Date3` does not have that problem

Comment: bad value means that it sometimes writes out 01.01.0001 and sometimes date. Its weird..

Comment: @AndrewBlack again: what inputs give you unexpected values? "sometimes" doesn't help! FWIW: what I'd do here is: `model.Date1.GetValueOrDefault() != DateTime.MinValue ? model.Date1.Value.ToShortDateString() : "Is not known";` (and similarly for `Date2` / `Date3`) - if we expect it could be 01-01-01; if that isn't a possibility, then just use `model.Date1.HasValue ? model.Date1.Value.ToShortDateString() : "Is not known";`

Comment: Thanks, that works. I guess because I send values from View (in my asp.net core mvc) data must have been converted...

Comment: You do know that a type of `DateTime?` means that it can contain a **null-value**? And a `.ToString()` will then return an empty string (instead of a NullReferenceException). I assume your `AsDateTime()` will then return the `default(DateTime)`, which is `DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: Yeah, that is propably the issue... Anyway thanks for spending your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the nullable types as follows.

```
model.Date1.HasValue ? model.Date1.Value.ToShortDateString() : "Unknown";
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Its clever and fast solution. I will aprove as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

You can also compare with `default` datetime value by `model.Date1.GetValueOrDefault() != default(DateTime)`.

`GetValueOrDefault` will return `default` value if `Date1` is `null`.

```
model.Date1.GetValueOrDefault() != default(DateTime) ? model.Date1.Value.ToShortDateString() : "Unknown";
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also very clever solution!